# Issues with replacing leafs in BST implementation

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, implementation

I'm working on a project where we are supposed to implement a BST via dataclass. The first "part" of the code works. It sorts 6 entries (key/value combo) according to size. However, the next step is to replace some values in the BST. I'm almost certain that the best way to do this is by checking the entire tree for key matches and then replacing the value of said key with the new value. However, the code only "semi" works.

```
@dataclass
class Node:
key: Any = None         # the key
value: Any = None       # the value
left: Any = None        # left child (a Node)
right: Any = None       # right child (a Node)

def put(self, key, value):
    new_leaf = Node(key, value)     # Below SHOULD check if there is a key match in either the 
                                    #left or right leaf.
    if self.left or self.right is not None:
        if self.left is not None:   #Checks left leaf for key match.
            if self.left.key == new_leaf.key:
                print("Match on SELF.LEFT.KEY:", self.left.key, new_leaf.key)
        if self.right is not None:  #Checks right leaf for key match.
            if self.right.key == new_leaf.key:
                print("Match on SELF.RIGHT.KEY:", self.right.key, new_leaf.key)
    if new_leaf.value < self.value: #Adds new leafs normally. This part (should) work(?).
        if self.left is None:
            self.left = Node(key, value, None, None)
        else:
            self.left.put(key, value)
    if new_leaf.value > self.value:
        if self.right is None:
            self.right = Node(key, value, None, None)
        else:
            self.right.put(key, value)
```

Here is the original output (when just adding key/values):

```
{ (Adam|27) (Ceve|37) (Ella|39) (Owen|40) (Zoe|41) (Fred|44)}
```

And here is the output when I try to replace key Ceve and key Zoe by adding them to the put method (Match on SELF.LEFT.KEY means that an identical key has been found in the tree and is to be replaced (later)):

```
Override existing values
Match on SELF.LEFT.KEY: Zoe Zoe
{ (Adam|27) (Ceve|37) (Ella|39) (Owen|40) (Zoe|41) (Fred|44) (Zoe|99) (Ceve|100)}
```

Now, it should print two "matches" but for some reason it doesn't detect Ceve. I've messed around with print functions to try and actually see whats going on and it seems to be that it never actually finds the Ceve leaf (obviously), but I don't know why that is.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what could be causing the issue?

Comment: If it's intended ignore me but you should write: `if self.left is not None or self.right is not None`. Otherwise `self.left = 0, [], "",` and others can produce a False there.

Comment: Your first if block has no else blocks and on matches just prints an output, are you sure you don't want to do something when there is match? Like return to abort or perform an exchange?

Comment: What is the advantage of a BST keyed by age when searching a name? None. So why you have a BST?

Comment: Secondly, if you would be able to find a node by name (key), you cannot update its value, because that update would violate the BST order. So you really should explain exactly what the requirements are, which is the expected output, etc.

Comment: No, not stupid, but I think we lack information here in order to give a useful answer. *"Its in the project instructions"*: could you quote them literally, so there is no misunderstanding possible?

Comment: *"Expected outcome is:"*: seems you didn't finish your comment. Better is to edit your question and add such information there. Also, the output you have mentioned in your question cannot be produced with the code you have provided... so something is missing there as well.